# Суждения черпают из забытых газет(,) времён очаковских и покорений Крыма

Tags: запятые

Нужна запятая? Я думаю, что да.

> Сужденья черпают из *забытых* газет(,) *времён очаковских и покорений Крыма*.

Comment: Ну типа определение идет после существительного, правило понимаешь. Но почему запятой нет после времен? Ведь там тоже определение после существительного. Алё куда правило смотрит в этот раз?

Comment: Да уж! Чтобы поставить здесь запятую,надо очень хорошо НЕ ЗНАТЬ грамматику, семантику, интонацию и правила. Обособить несогласованное определение в форме Р.п. – это совершенно немыслимое дело.

Comment: Это вы сделали, когда был вопрос про *Мой большой участок(,) длиною в 100 метров* (или что-то похожее).

Comment: Падежи разные: Р.п. (времен) и Т.п. (длиною).   Они не взаимозаменяемые, разные значения,поэтому сравнивать примеры нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

• Первое. *Правильная* цитата выглядит так:

*А судьи кто? — За древностию лет

К свободной жизни их вражда непримирима,

Сужденья черпают из забытых газет

Времен очаковских и **покоренья** Крыма.*
А. Грибоедов. Горе от ума

• Второе. Как только мы поставим запятую в указанном месте, возникает **неправильный по смыслу** однородный ряд:
черпают (из чего? откуда?) — из газет, времён и покорения.
Не... Черпают только из газет.

• Третье. Слово *времена* в этом контексте имеет такое значение: "исторический период в развитии человечества; определённая эпоха или отдельный этап в жизни народа, государства, общества".

Практически всегда оно **нуждается в определении** (согласованном или несогласованном), указывающим на то, какие же именно это времена:
времена Екатерины, рыцарские времена, времена оны, времена ветхозаветные, *времена очаковские, времена покорения Крыма*.
Поэтому и нет запятой после слова "времён".

• Окончательное. Нет, дополнительные запятые не нужны — знаки стоят правильно.